# R remove repeated digit sequences

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to remove all digits in a string except the first set of digits. So in other words, all repeating sets of digits, there could be 1 sets or 10+ sets in the string but I only want to keep the first set along with the rest of the string.

For example, the following string:

```
x <- 'foo123bar123baz123456abc1111def123456789'
```

The result would be:

```
foo123barbazabcdef
```

I am have tried using `gsub` and replacing `\d+` with an empty string but this replaces all digits in the string, I have also tried using groups to capture some of the results but had no luck.

Answer (score 7):

Using gsub you can use the `\G` feature, an anchor that can match at one of two positions.

```
x <- 'foo123bar123baz123456abc1111def123456789'
gsub('(?:\\d+|\\G(?<!^)\\D*)\\K\\d*', '', x, perl=T)
# [1] "foo123barbazabcdef"
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?:           # group, but do not capture:
  \d+         #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
 |            # OR
  \G(?<!^)    #   contiguous to a precedent match, not at the start of the string
  \D*         #   non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times)
)\K           # end of grouping and reset the match from the result
\d*           # digits (0-9) (0 or more times)
```

Alternatively, you can use an optional group:

```
gsub('(?:^\\D*\\d+)?\\K\\d*', '', x, perl=T)
```

Another way that I find useful and does not require `(*SKIP)(*F)` backtracking verbs or the `\G` and `\K` feature is to use the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator in context placing what you want to match in a capturing group on the left side and place what you want to exclude on the right side, (saying *throw this away, it's garbage*...)

```
gsub('^(\\D*\\d+)|\\d+', '\\1', x)
```

Comment: The master strikes again

Comment: Not to pick on you but your second way won't work if the subject string begins with digits http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/140, because the right side can swallow the left side you should reverse their order `^(\D*\d+)|\d+` and replace with `\1` http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/141 - a variation from Avinash's solution, or `^\D*\d+\K|\d+`

Comment: @alphabravo it was a typo, I fixed the second option.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this through PCRE verb [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/3297613).

```
^\D*\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+
```

`^\D*\d+` matches all the characters from the start upto the first number. `(*SKIP)(*F)` causes the match to fail and then the regex engine tries to match the characters using the pattern which was at the right side of `|` that is `\d+` against the remaining string. Because `(*SKIP)(*F)` is a PCRE verb, you must need to enable `perl=TRUE` parameter.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hL2lE6/8)

Code:

```
> x <- 'foo123bar123baz123456abc1111def123456789'
> gsub("^\\D*\\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|\\d+", "", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "foo123barbazabcdef"
```